# Evaluating a contour integral where $C$ is a square

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametric

I've been working problems all day so maybe I'm just confusing myself but in order to do this. I have to the take the integral along each contour $C_1-C_4$. My issue is how to convert to parametric functions in order to this so that I can integrate

[image]

Comment: $1/z$ is not holomorphic everywhere inside the square.

Answer (score 3):

No because $\dfrac1z$ is not defined when $z=0$. You need a holomorphic function on the whole square for this to hold. This integral should be the same as for the circle, namely $2\pi i$.

Comment: so I take the sum of the integral along $C_1, C_2, C_3, and C_4?$

Comment: Yes. This problem needs to be done "by hand", i.e. you actually gotta calculate the integral.

Comment: @user2345215, wouldnt the answere here just be $2\pi i???$

Comment: @cele Isn't this what I said? But you still need to compute it if you don't have any other theorems. Dustin already gave you the equations of the curves, note that in your picture you have the last segment in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1/z$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric equations for the square going counter clockwise:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\gamma_1 &= 2 + 2i(2t-1)&&{}\quad 0\leq t\leq 1\\
\gamma_2 &= 2i + 2(3-2t)&&{}\quad 1\leq t\leq 2\\
\gamma_3 &= -2 + 2i(5-2t)&&{}\quad 2\leq t\leq 3\\
\gamma_4 &= -2i + 2(2t - 7)&&{}\quad 3\leq t\leq 4
\end{alignat}

Comment: thank you. I can take it from here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with or allowed to use residues, but if you calculate the residue of the pole in zero (its value is $1$), note that it is the only pole and use the residue formula*, you get $2\pi i$.

* that for residues $a_k$ inside $\gamma$, we have $\int_\gamma f(z) \ \text{d}z = 2\pi i\sum a_k$

Comment: No, I did know know about residues at this time

Comment: Ok! If you're following a course in complex analysis then you'll probably encounter this later on. The whole theory of the Cauchy integral formula and other related stuff concerning simplification of integrals around certain points is a big part of what makes complex analysis so useful and elegant. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are allowed to use the Cauchy Integral Formula, but consider $f(z) = 1$ which is analytic in and on the region bounded by your curve. Then you have $2\pi if(0) = \int_C\frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i$.